# help with xcode warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I get the following warning in my appdelegate.m file:

```
warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct QuestionnaireViewController *', expected 'struct UIViewController *' when passing argument 1 of 'setRootViewController:' from distinct Objective-C type
```

QuestionnaireViewController subclasses UIViewController so I'm, not sure why it's causing problems...

Comment: Post some code, please. What line called `setRootViewController:`? How is `QuestionnaireViewController` defined? Etc...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you remember to `#import "QuestionnaireViewController.h"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you probably forward-declared the class using `@class QuestionnaireViewController` and didn't actually import the header. If you did this, the compiler only knows that the class exists, but it doesn't know anything else about it, so it doesn't know that it is a subclass of `UIViewController`. Make sure you `#import "QuestionnaireViewControllier.h"` inside of your .m file.